# emberjs - print to console all paths in object

Tags: ember.js, console, ember-old-router

I want see all possible paths in some object. How can i do this?

Example i have:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
enableLogging: true,
location: 'hash',

root: Em.Route.extend({
    // EVENTS
    gotoAbout: Ember.Route.transitionTo('about'),
    gotoProjects: Ember.Route.transitionTo('projects'),
    gotoTechnology: Ember.Route.transitionTo('technology'),
    gotoContact: Ember.Route.transitionTo('contact'),

    // STATES
    about: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('about');
        }
    }),
...
})
```

I want print to console ( something like `console.log()` ) all possible path in `App.Router`. How can i do this? How can i check the "tree" in objects in emberjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd iterate over `childStates`, and make a recursive function.

```js
var walkState = function(state){
  console.log(state.get('path'));
  state.get('childStates').forEach(function(childState){
    walkState(childState);        
  });                    
}        

App.router.get('childStates').forEach(function(state){
   walkState(state);        
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have other question:
My the biggest problem is i cant debug my code. Errors in console dont give me full information about errors. I dont know what variables i can read from where and what mistakes i did. Do you use some addtional programs/plugins for browser to get more information about code?

Comment: No additional plugins, just Chrome and the debugger. I think this video from Tom Dale http://vimeo.com/37539737 could be useful for you

Comment: Oh... i didnt know about few thinks... Thank you very much!